# Convert to uppercase just after a period or at the beginning of the paragraph

Tags: php

Convert to uppercase just after a period or at the beginning of the paragraph. if you can help me thank you very much

```
$chain= $_POST['box']; //I send a text
$paragraph= ucwords($chain);//It only capitalizes the first letter of the entire paragraph
echo $paragraph;
```

**example paragraph** the first letter of each paragraph must be capital letter

**l**orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**l**orem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Comment: `text-transform: uppercase;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$newStr = "";
$chain= $_POST['box']; //I send a text

$strArr = explode(".", $str);

foreach($strArr as $strPart){
  $paragraph .= ". ".ucfirst($strPart);
  
}

echo ltrim($paragraph, '.');
```